# Semantic search

Tags: algorithm, solr, nlp, semantics, apache-stanbol

I want to build an algorithm as follows -

Lets say, user first search for keyword "tablet" and then again search for "Apple", so i should be able to populate 2nd search result which gives information on Apple tablet. Another example, first I search for "Android" and then search for "mobile phone",  so I should populate 2nd search result on Android phone.

What is the best way of implementing such algorithm? Using Python, Java or other language?

Is Apache stanbol/Solr good enough for such algorithm?

Comment: Did you mean that you just want to combine second search term with the first one? If the first is "phone tablet" and the second is "Samsung". You want to get "Samsung phone" and "Samsung Tablet"?

Comment: No, its not just the combining both search term, rather it is the context of search term, in which context user is searching for what.

Comment: Can't you just suggest when they type the search term on the form? If your web is selling phone and tablet, you can provide a list of possible keyword, and then create a simple suggest program.

Comment: this is not the solution i'm looking for. and this is not how semantics or context based search work

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://lucidworks.com/resources/webinars/natural-language-search-with-solr/). It is something similar to what you're trying to do. Might give you a place to start.